# MKAnnotationView images has replaced after zoom or reopen tap

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am parse Json with coordinates and download individual profile image for each annotation view. When I do zoom or move on map I see what images replaced on wrong places. For example I have annotation view with coordinates 111.1111, 111.1111. First time image and coordinate is correct, but after moves/zoom/reopen tab with map I see other annotation view with coordinates 222.222, 222.222 with image which is suitable for 111.111, 111.1111.

```
(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    static NSString *identifier = @"SYLocationItem";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[SYLocationItem class]]) {

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

            SYJabberClient *client = [SYJabberClient sharedClient];
            [client retrieveProfileForUserWithEmail:[(SYLocationItem*)annotation email]
                                   withSuccessBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error) {
                                       if (dict) {

                                           UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"imageFile"];

                                           UIImage *displayImage = [UIImage circularScaleNCrop:image
                                                                                      withRect:
                                                                    CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,30.0f,30.0f)];
                                           annotationView.image = displayImage;

                                       }
                                   }];
                    } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        return annotationView;
       }  
    return nil;      
}
```

In this code now I get image from local, but if downloading images I have same issue.

Comment: Looks like a view re-use issue.  If annotationView is not nil, code updates the annotation property but the image is still for some other annotation.  Set the view's image regardless of whether it is dequeued or not.

Comment: real, it was because image been setting when annotation view nil/not nil block. I try set view's image regardless of whether it is dequeued or not and problem now is resolve. Thanks!